# Множественный выбор меток yandex map

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите возможно ли кликая по меткам на карте получить множественный выбор точек для последующего группового действия например назначение исполнителя для данных адресов?

Comment: а какой смысл задавать вопрос, на который очень легко самостоятельно получить абсолютно точный ответ буквально за несколько секунд, запустив яндекс.карты и пощёлкав мышкой?

Comment: Так я не нашел, что бы можно было сделать выбранными несколько точек. Выбираешь новую прошлая сбрасывается и выбирается новая.

Answer (score 0):

Яндекс карты в принципе не реализуют такого понятия, «как выбор меток». При клике на метку по умолчанию просто активируется привязанный к метке балун. И активным остаётся (и должен) только один такой балун.

Если вам требуется каким-то образом выделять отдельные метки, следует просто [отслеживать определённые действия](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_events) над ними и вносить эти объекты в ваши персональные списочные массивы.